# Get range between colors in MS Access color format

Tags: sql, colors, hex, rgb, bgr

In database, I have stored colors only in MS Access color format (decimal format of BGR): it looks like 8689859 => brown => #c39884 ...
But I need to filter by the color range, I mean user use the color picker and pick the eg. #ffffff color. And I would like to return all rows with color alike the #ffffff (not exactly the same color but +- in same range).

Is something like that possible?

Comment: please define alike..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the =- range should apply to each of the separate colour elements in the BGR value. In this case you need to extract these elements, like this:

```
SELECT colour
      ,Fix([Colour]/(256*256)) as B
      ,Fix(([Colour]-Fix([Colour]/(256*256))*256*256)/256) as G
      ,[Colour]-Fix([Colour]/(256*256))*256*256-Fix(([Colour]-Fix([Colour]/(256*256))*256*256)/256)*256 as R
FROM MyColours
```

I recommend you put these into separate functions like GetR, GetB, GetG

You can even make the computed fields and apply them to your table:

[image: Colours Table with computed fields]

Now, to lookup your table you need to split the selected colour in B G R elements as well:

```
Dim selectedColour as Integer
Dim rr as Integer
Dim gg as Integer
Dim bb as Integer
selectedColour = 11124168 ' A9BDC8 - selected from the colour picker
rr = getR(selectedColour)
gg = getG(selectedColour)
bb = getB(selectedColour)
```

If you have the computed fields in the table then the query will be:

```
SELECT colour 
FROM MyColours
WHERE B BETWEEN bb-4 AND bb+4 
AND G BETWEEN gg-4 AND gg+4 
AND R BETWEEN rr-4 AND rr+4
```

If you do not want the computed fields use the VBA functions:

```
SELECT colour 
FROM MyColours
WHERE getB(colour) BETWEEN bb-4 AND bb+4 
AND getG(Colour) BETWEEN gg-4 AND gg+4 
AND getR(Colour) BETWEEN rr-4 AND rr+4
```